# How to generate all the possible combinations of exchange rates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, tuples

Given a table of tuples of currency and exchange rate, such as the following:

```
EUR CHF 1.20
USD EUR 0.80
CHF JPY 1.30
```

How can I simply generate all the exchange rate between currency (A,B) and also (B,A)?

I would like to have the following:

```
EUR CHF
CHF EUR

EUR USD
USD EUR

USD CHF
CHF USD
```

with all the possible combinations, i.e. a rate can be derived from multiple rates by chaining them

```
A to B * B to C * C to D = A to D
```

Comment: but presumably you'd need to calculate the shortest path between two currencies?

Comment: the size of the problem is negligeable but of course the shortest would be better

Comment: Is it possible that `EUR CHF` is not the inverse of `CHF EUR`? i.e. if there is a spread in the prices, shortest path would be critical, right?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: sql server 2005 @GarethD , no, this is not possible A->B = 1/(B->A)

Comment: Through chaining, those rates give you USD -> JPY of 1.248, so the length of a chain is going to introduce rounding issues (I'm sure you have more than three rates) or paradoxical results where two differing routes give differing results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [Recursive Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Setup:

```
Create Table ExchangeRates (
    FromCurrency char(3),
    ToCurrency char(3),
    Rate decimal(10, 2),
    Constraint PK_ExchangeRates Primary Key (FromCurrency, ToCurrency)
);

Create Index IX_ToCurrency On ExchangeRates(ToCurrency, FromCurrency, Rate);

Insert Into ExchangeRates (FromCurrency, ToCurrency, Rate) Values
  ('EUR', 'CHF', 1.20),
  ('USD', 'EUR', 0.80),
  ('CHF', 'JPY', 1.30);
```

The CTE, which assumes all currency codes are exactly three characters:

```
With AllExchanges as (
    Select
        FromCurrency,
        ToCurrency,
        Rate
    From
        ExchangeRates
    Union
    Select
        ToCurrency,
        FromCurrency,
        Cast(1.0 / Rate As Decimal(10, 2))
    From
        ExchangeRates
)
, Paths as (
    Select
        FromCurrency,
        cast(FromCurrency as varchar(max)) As ExchangePath,
        ToCurrency,
        Rate
    From
        AllExchanges a
    Union All
    Select
        p.FromCurrency,
        p.ExchangePath + ',' + p.ToCurrency,
        a.ToCurrency,
        Cast(p.Rate * a.Rate as Decimal(10, 2))
    From
        Paths p
            Inner Join
        AllExchanges a
            On p.ToCurrency = a.FromCurrency
    Where
        p.ExchangePath Not Like '%' + a.ToCurrency + '%'
    )
Select
    FromCurrency,
    ExchangePath + ',' + ToCurrency As ExchangePath,
    ToCurrency,
    Rate
From
    Paths
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fdc5

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can find to do this is using a LOOP, All my queries below use this sample data:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (FromCurrency VARCHAR(3), ToCurrency VARCHAR(3), ExchangeRate DECIMAL(10, 5));
INSERT @T VALUES
    ('EUR', 'CHF', 1.20),
    ('USD', 'EUR', 0.80),
    ('CHF', 'JPY', 1.30);
```

The first step is to get all the reciprocal exchange rates (i.e. B -> A from the table of A -> B) as these are the easiest to get:

```
DECLARE @TempExchangeRates TABLE (FromCurrency VARCHAR(3), ToCurrency VARCHAR(3), ExchangeRate DECIMAL(10, 5));

INSERT @TempExchangeRates (FromCurrency, ToCurrency, ExchangeRate)
SELECT  FromCurrency, ToCurrency, ExchangeRate
FROM    @T
UNION
SELECT  ToCurrency, FromCurrency, CAST(1 / ExchangeRate AS DECIMAL(10, 5))
FROM    @T t
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    @T t2
            WHERE   t.FromCurrency = t2.ToCurrency
            AND     t.ToCurrency = t2.FromCurrency
        )
```

At this point we have:

```
CHF EUR 0.83333
CHF JPY 1.30000
EUR CHF 1.20000
EUR USD 1.25000
JPY CHF 0.76923
USD EUR 0.80000
```

So we are still missing

```
CHF --> USD 
EUR --> JPY 
JPY --> CHF 
JPY --> EUR 
USD --> EUR
```

You need to keep performing this join

```
SELECT  a.FromCurrency, b.ToCurrency, CAST(a.ExchangeRate * b.ExchangeRate AS DECIMAL(10, 5))
FROM    @TempExchangeRates a
        INNER JOIN @TempExchangeRates b
            ON a.ToCurrency = b.FromCurrency
            AND a.FromCurrency != b.ToCurrency
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    @TempExchangeRates c
            WHERE   a.FromCurrency = c.FromCurrency
            AND     b.ToCurrency = c.ToCurrency
        )
```

And inserting the results until all combinations have been found:

```
WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT @TempExchangeRates (FromCurrency, ToCurrency, ExchangeRate)
        SELECT  DISTINCT a.FromCurrency, b.ToCurrency, CAST(a.ExchangeRate * b.ExchangeRate AS DECIMAL(10, 5))
        FROM    @TempExchangeRates a
                INNER JOIN @TempExchangeRates b
                    ON a.ToCurrency = b.FromCurrency
                    AND a.FromCurrency != b.ToCurrency
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS
                (   SELECT  1
                    FROM    @TempExchangeRates c
                    WHERE   a.FromCurrency = c.FromCurrency
                    AND     b.ToCurrency = c.ToCurrency
                )

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN
                BREAK;
            END
    END
```

On the first loop this will retrieve

```
CHF USD 1.04166
EUR JPY 1.56000
JPY EUR 0.64102
USD CHF 0.96000
```

Then on the second

```
JPY USD 0.80128
USD JPY 1.24800
```

Then all 12 tuples will have been found.